# Парсинг сайта python

Tags: python, парсер

Проблема такая: с браузера сайт открывается на ура, но при отправлении ему get запроса с помощью requests возвращает ошибку 403. В чем может быть проблема?

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://<тут адрес сайта>")
```

Причем так происходит только с этим сайтом(hltv.org). На нем стоит какая то защита?

Comment: используйте headers от любого брайзера, без него сайт определяет, что работает именно программа и блочит ее

Comment: @danilshik а как их сформировать?

Comment: @danilshik {'user-agent': 'your-own-user-agent/0.0.1'} вот такое вставил и заработало! Спасибо!

Comment: не успел добавить комментарий)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве примера, список user-agent можете найти в интернете, либо просто скопировать из своего браузера

```
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0'
        }
r = requests.get(url_page, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно имитировать вход человека, некоторые сайты блокируют программы
import requests

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}

r = requests.get("https://www.hltv.org/", headers=headers)

print(r) #<Response [200]>
```